# Using Javascript to Replace Link

Tags: javascript

I'm using this Javascript code in an attempt to replace the links on a page with a message that says "DOWNLOAD", with a hyperlink that leads to my registration page.

The problem is the "DOWNLOAD" text is not replacing the original link text. The original link is displayed. It does lead to the registration page, but again, the original link on the page is still visible as text.

Any ideas?

```
<script>
    function replaceLinks() {
        var links = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
        for (var i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
            links[i].innerHtml = 'DOWNLOAD' + 
                    '<a href="register.php">register here</a>.';
            links[i].href = 'register.php';
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: You're putting a link inside another link. I don't think that will work.

Comment: It's `innerHTML`, not `innerHtml`. Case is significant.

Answer (score 1):

It should be:

```
function replaceLinks() {
    var links = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
    for (var i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
        links[i].innerHTML = 'DOWNLOAD register here.';
        links[i].href = 'register.php';
    }
}
```

The property is `innerHTML`, the last part is all uppercase. And you don't need to nest another link inside the link.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you have a capitalization issue - it should be innerHTML. You can also remove other parts of your code:

```
function replaceLinks() {
var links = document.getElementsByTagName('a');

for (var i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
    console.log(links);
    links[i].innerHTML = 'DOWNLOAD';
    links[i].href = 'register.php';
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

In jQuery way,

```
function replaceLinks() {
    var links = $('a');
    for (var i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
        links[i].html('DOWNLOAD register here.');
        links[i].attr('href') = 'register.php';
    }
}
```